# To find the speed of a travelling pulse from given equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

A travelling pulse is given by the following equation $$f(x,t) = A \exp\frac{2abxt-a^2x^2-b^2t^2}{c^2}$$

What I did: Evaluated $\partial^2_x$ and $\partial^2_t$ and plugged the values into the $$\partial^2_xf(x,t)=\frac{1}{v^2}\partial^2_tf$$ to solve for $v$ but my answer didn't match to any of the answers given  below: [image]

Infact my answer wasn't even in such a simple fractional form. I don't understand where I am wrong.

Comment: Hint: Does the expression $2abxt-a^2x^2-b^2t^2$ look as if it could be simplified?

Comment: Indeed! Why didn't I think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a simpler approach: When you have pulse with velocity $v$, the value of the function has to be constant along lines given by equation $x = x_0 + vt$. In other words:
$$
f(x_0 + vt,t) = \rm{const}
$$

Before we proceed further, we notice that the argument of exp can be simplified like this:

$$
f(x,t) = A \exp \biggl[-\biggl( \frac{ax-bt}{c} \biggr)^2\biggr]
$$

So, let's plug in $x = x_0 + vt$

$$
f(x_0 + vt,t) = A \exp \biggl[-\biggl( \frac{a(x_0+vt)-bt}{c} \biggr)^2\biggr] = \rm{const}
$$

The only thing that can break constantness of this expression is the numerator of the fraction inside (because nothing else contains $t$), so we must satisfy:
$$
a(x_0+vt)-bt = ax_0 + avt - bt = \rm{const}
$$

For this to hold, the terms with $t$ just have to compensate each other, so:
$$
avt - bt = 0
$$

This yields result:
$$
v = \frac{b}{a}
$$

Comment: Please do not give explicit answers to homework questions

Comment: I understand. I have hidden the question for a while, but now OP obviously solved the thing, i undeleted it to show an alternative solution.